# How to use body from API

Tags: node.js

This probably is most likely a dumb question but how after using a GET request for API data do you use an integer from body to perform a function,  in this case i want to divide 3rd number from body of var array 1 with 3rd number of body of var array 2:

`[4385.1,16.7770791,4385.3,12.74414776,261.2,0.0633,4385.3,23078.11968457,4390,4089.9]`
`[326.5,15,326.51,0.01504489,10.9,0.0345,326.5,94510.58029456,329.56,314.14]`

```
var request = require('request')

var array1 = request.get('https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/ticker/tBTCUSD',
function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body)
});

var array2 = request.get('https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/ticker/tETHUSD',
function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body)
});
```

Comment: You should use promises.

Answer (score 1):

If this is literally your response:

```
[4385.1,16.7770791,4385.3,12.74414776,261.2,0.0633,4385.3,23078.11968457,4390,4089.9] [326.5,15,326.51,0.01504489,10.9,0.0345,326.5,94510.58029456,329.56,314.14]
```

Then, you need to first parse it with `JSON.parse()` and then you can access the numbers in the array.  To do a second one after the first has finished, you can embed the 2nd request inside the first one and then you can easily have both sets of data in the same place.

Keep in mind that `request.get()` is asynchronous, so you can't just assign the result to an array like you were trying to do.

```
request.get('https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/ticker/tBTCUSD', function (err1, response, body1) {
    if (err1) {
        // error handling here
    } else {
        let array1 = JSON.parse(body1);
        request.get('https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/ticker/tETHUSD', function (err2, response, body2) {
            if (err2) {
                // error handling here
            } else {
                let array2 = JSON.parse(body2);
                // now you have both arrays here
                let answer = array1[2] / array2[2];
                // do something with answer here
            }                
        });
    }
});
```

---

A more modern way to do this would be to use promises and to use the `request-promise` library instead of the `request` library and you can even let the library parse the JSON for you (something the `request` library can also do).  This runs both requests in parallel and then `Promise.all()` tells us when both requests are done and gives us the two results in order:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
Promise.all([
    rp.get({uri:'https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/ticker/tBTCUSD', json:true}), 
    rp.get({uri:'https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/ticker/tETHUSD', json:true})
]).then(function(results) {
    let array1 = results[0], array2 = results[1];
    let answer = array1[2] / array2[2];
    // do something with answer here
}).catch(function(err) {
    // handle error here
});
```